# How can I solve a system of two equations, like $A + B = 13$ and $2D + B = 13$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I am currently studying for my [SSAT](http://www.ssat.org/) and this question appeared in my practice book:

> When $A + B = 13$ and $2D + B = 13$, what is the value of $D$?
>
> (A) 13
>
> (B) 5
>
> (C) -5
>
> (D) -7
>
> (E) It cannot be determined from the information given

How can I go about solving this and other questions that are similar in the future?

Comment: Try $A=0$, $B=13$, $D=0$, and then try $A=13$, $B=0$ and $D=13/2$.

Comment: @Pp.. how does that work?

Comment: In general you can organize the system, do elimination of variables, i.e. do row reduction of the matrix of the system to bring it to triangular form. The presence of more pivots than variables will tell you that it has many solutions. It is an undetermined system.

Comment: In this problem the system is already in triangular form, if you organize the variables as $A,B,D$, for example.

Comment: @Pp.. yeah, my school hasn't taught me anything about this sort of stuff [yet?]

Comment: You really don't need anything about matrix transformations(row reduction) and stuff, and those things will (most likely) never be taught unless you proceed to read maths at uni. Really only thing you need in this question is to see that when you subtract first equation from second one you will get $A=2D$ and ANY set of values satisfying this relationship will satisfy equations. For instance, $(A,D)=(2,1),(4,2),(-2,-1)$ etc.. there are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses nothing more than basic algebra. The basic idea is to solve everything in terms of $D$ and see if this limits the values of $D$.

If we solve the second equation for $B$ we get
$$B=13-2D$$

Solving the first equation for $A$ then substituting our expression for $B$ we get
$$A=13-B=13-(13-2D)=2D$$

We can easily check that these expressions solve the two equations.

This shows that $D$ could have any values and we could still find solutions to the equations. Therefore, we cannot determine the value of $D$ from the information given, and the correct answer to the problem is **(E)**.